# Scrapy ignores requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a Spider and I have this code because probably the response might not be 200(OK)

```
class FightersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fighters_spider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=' + l + '&page=all'
                for l in list(string.ascii_lowercase)]

    def parse(self,response):
        if response.status != 200:
            return scrapy.Request(url = response.url,callback = self.parse,
                                dont_filter = True)
        # Did some other stuff
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = link,callback = self.fighter_parse)

    def fighter_parse(self,response):
        if response.status != 200:
            return scrapy.Request(url = response.url,callback = self.fighter_parse,
                                dont_filter = True)
    # Do some stuff 
    # Function does not return anything
```

and when I try the `parse` method individually(imagine function returns `None` and does not yield a request) this works but when I have it as above when one of the `start_urls` returns `404` the crawler does not try to redo the request.Furthermore the callback at `fighter_parse` method works normally. Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: 404 means the page is not there, I don't think redo the request will solve the problem

Comment: This specific webpage has that bug. For example, when I was surfing at this page it gave me a 404 error but when I refreshed the page it showed to me normally. And as I said at the thread when I try it individually it might give me some 404s but after it returns 200.

Comment: to redo the process, you should check for `404` the way yo did it for `200`, and repeat until exact number of time or something other than `404`

Comment: I checked the log, and I saw that the request was done once and returns 404 and does not try to redo the request...

Comment: you need something like this `if response.status == 404: while(response.status!=200): redo`

Comment: I also tried checking if `response.status==404` and did not worked and I think why we talk about that? What's the difference than checking `response.status==200`? Furthermore the while is not needed because I some some kind of recursive while because when the request is done calls the `parse` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are built-in Scrapy features for that: [RETRY_HTTP_CODES](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-http-codes) and [RETRY_TIMES](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-times)

Comment: I’m gonna test this features, but why my code is not working like I wrote it?

Comment: This really worked for me, but because I want to know where I am wrong, why the code that I wrote didn’t worked?

Comment: Because to process 404 **error** you need to use separate callback. You can specify it using `errback` keyword of your `Request` object.

Comment: But when I Run this program it does what I want at fighter_parse function